# Doing "uint8x8x4_t - 128" then divising this by 2

Tags: neon

I'm a bit mixed up about how to achieve a division by a scalar on Neon in a specific case.

In a c++ context, I'm achieving a contrast effect with a very rudimentary algorithm:

```
if (currentEffect == "contrast_with_cpp")
{
    r += ((r - 128) / 2);
    g += ((g - 128) / 2);
    b += ((b - 128) / 2);
}
```

I would like to port this algorithm to neon intrinsics.

I've tried, but I'm totally newbie to this approach, and I cannot debug this code in Visual Studio. It is compiled at startup and integrated to a Windows Phone application.

```
if (currentEffect == "contrast_with_neon") /* Experimental, not working *
{
    // To test
    copy_rgb = rgb;

    // Substract 128 from the copy, prevent it should be a signed variable
```

?

```
    // Get half value from copy and put it in another copy

    uint8x8x4_t otherCopy = interleaved;
    otherCopy.val[2] = vmul_n_f32(copy_rgb.val[2], 0.5);
    otherCopy.val[1] = vmul_n_f32(copy_rgb.val[1], 0.5);
    otherCopy.val[0] = vmul_n_f32(copy_rgb.val[0], 0.5);

    // Add it to the first copy

    copy_rgb.val[2] = vadd_u8(copy_rgb.val[2], otherCopy.val[2]);
    copy_rgb.val[1] = vadd_u8(copy_rgb.val[2], otherCopy.val[1]);
    copy_rgb.val[0] = vadd_u8(copy_rgb.val[2], otherCopy.val[0]);       

    rgb = copy_rgb;
}
```

Is this achievable using intrinsics?

[Edit] I guess the color data structure is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455700/depth-transformation-with-arm-neon-intrinsics)

Answer (score 0):

Stop wasting your time with intrinsics. It's a real pain, especially with gcc.

Try this in assembly :

```
vmov.i16 qMdeian, #128 // put this line outside of loop
// -----------------------------------------------

vmovl.u8 qRed, dRed
vmovl.u8 qGrn, dGrn
vmovl.u8 qBlu, dBlu

vsub.s16 qRedTemp, qRed, qMedian
vsub.s16 qGrnTemp, qGrn, qMedian
vsub.s16 qBluTemp, qBlu, qMedian

vshr.s16 qRedTemp, #2
vshr.s16 qGrnTemp, #2
vshr.s16 qBluTemp, #2

vadd.s16 qRed, qRedTemp
vadd.s16 qGrn, qGrnTemp
vadd.s16 qBlu, qBluTemp

vqmovun.s16 dRed, qRed
vqmovun.s16 dGrn, qGrn
vqmovun.s16 dBlu, qBlu
```

If the does saturate at 255, and any negative values will become zeros which I assume is intended.

PS : What are you doing with float?

Comment: Oh, thanks for the advice. But there will be a difference in the execution time speed I guess? I'm currently working at 15 fps in cases where I'm only using 128 bits neon operations.

Comment: It decreases at 8-9 fps for normal C++.

Comment: About float, it was just to randomly put a cast that would compile without error, not the actual code as I should instead multiply by a byte then >> shift right.